# Conditional Probability : How to get $P(Y_{1} \mid S_{1} ,Y_{2} \mid S_{2}) = P((Y_{1},Y_{2}) \mid (S_{1},S_{2}))$

Tags: probability

> - Given $S_1$,the probability that $Y_1$ and $S_1$ are matching is $P(Y_1\mid S_1)$
> - Given $S_2$ ,the probability that $Y_2$ and $S_2$ are matching is $P(Y_2 \mid S_2)$
> - Also , whether $Y_1$ and $S_1$ are matching is independent of whether $Y_2$ and $S_2$ are matching
> - So I can get : $P(Y_1\mid S_1 , Y_2 \mid S_2) = P(Y_1 \mid S_1) \cdot P(Y_2|S_2)$

**My Question :**

Can I get the following equation :

> $P(Y_1 \mid S_1 ,Y_2 \mid S_2) = P((Y_1,Y_2) \mid (S_1,S_2))$
>
> OR
>
> $P(Y_1 \mid S_1 , Y_2 \mid S_2) = P((Y_1,Y_2) \mid (S_1,S_2)) + P((Y_2,Y_1) \mid (S_2,S_1))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notation seems nonsensical, but I suspect you mean something along the following lines:

For $i\in\{1,2\}$, let $E_i$ be the event $Y_i = S_i$. Then
$$\begin{align}P(E_1 E_2\mid S_1 S_2) &= P(E_1 \mid S_1 S_2 E_2)\cdot P(E_2\mid S_1 S_2)\\
&= P(E_1\mid S_1)\cdot P(E_2\mid S_2)
\end{align}
$$

where the second line follows from the first line **if** every event involving only subscript $1$ is independent of every event involving only subscript $2$, and vice versa. (In my notation, $AB$ denotes the intersection of events $A$ and $B$.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer is exactly what I want.